# is there a better way to collect alternative symbols from a string and combining in python?

Tags: python, string, performance, split

I just started learning Python. I came across slicing in Python 3. I'm working on a problem where I need to collect alternating symbols from a given string and combine them with the remaining symbols from the given string after removal of alternative symbols and finally combine them both.

I tried this way.  Is there a way to make this code faster?

This is given `1n2a3m4e5i$s` and expected output is `nameis,12345$`

```
str="1n2a3m4e5i$s" # this is given to you
str1=str[0::2]
str2=str[1::2]
print(str2+","+str1) # this is required at the end
```

Comment: The slicing notation should call directly into C code, so it should be pretty fast.  Is there a specific performance issue that you are finding? (For example, the code is slow on _really_ long strings?)

Comment: I agree, this code take 200 ns on my machine, which is rather fast for a Python code!

Comment: @snakecharmerb ,hi i'm not good at coding, this how i was thinking. since i'm calling the str twice ,once for str1 and another time for str2. I thought if the string is big this might take some time.(Not sure whether this is correct or not). I thought to separate two string just by calling once.(And again i'm new to coding itself started with python).